# Guardar modificación de datos de un fichero XML en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy modificando el valor que me aparece en un listBox con los datos que he cargado desde un fichero XML pero cuando hago la modificación y guardo el fichero, este no se me guarda con las modificaciones que he realizado en la información. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Este es el código que tengo para modificar el dato:

```
int valorPulsado = listBox.SelectedIndex;
listBox.Items.RemoveAt(valorPulsado); 
listBox.Items.Insert(valorPulsado, "\t" + txtBoxModificar.Text);
txtBoxModificar.Text = "";
```

Y para guardar el documento XML, utilizo el siguiente código:

```
docXml.Save(guardarArchivo.FileName);
```

Cuando le doy a guardar, indico donde guardar el fichero y cuando voy a comprobar lo que ha guardado, solo aparece el fichero con la información original.

**docXml** y **guardarArchivo** son como he llamado a los objetos que he creado del **XmlDocument** y del **SaveFileDialog**.

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: En el código que muestras, no vemos en que momento actualizas el xml con los datos de listbox. Lo único que vemos es que actualizas datos en el listbox.

Comment: Bienvenido para ayudarte la pregunta debe de cumplir con [mcve] así que te invito a leerlo y editar la pregunta

Comment: Hola Pikoh, a qué te refieres con lo de actualizar el xml con los datos del listbox? Eso es lo que tengo para que se modifique. Entonces el problema puede ser ese, que no actualizo el xml... Y cómo lo actualizo, no sabría bien ahora... Gracias

Comment: Es un poco complicado sin ver mas código, pero básicamente supongo que tu estas cargando los datos del xml en el listbox, y ahi haces las modificaciones. Tienes que buscar la manera despues de pasar los datos actualizados del listbox al xml (o generar uno nuevo) que será el que posteriormente almacenes en el archivo

Comment: Eso es! eso es lo que pensé, el problema es que no se como pasar esas modificaciones al XML, porque donde manejos los datos del XML y los agrego al listBox es desde el botón cargar XML. Con el botón modificar es donde utilizo el código que he mostrado, es todo el código que tengo en la acción de ese botón. No se si es de mucha ayuda el código que he pasado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes guardarlo con `File.WriteAllText`, lo que sí, primero lo tendrías que convertir a string..

```
string xml = string.Empty;
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            xml.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
            xmlTextWriter.Flush();
            xml = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
File.WriteAllText(ruta, xml);
```

Espero que te sea útil... Saludos

Comment: Y cómo puedo pasar esos valores al XML y que se modifiquen, para que cuando guarde el fichero, al abrirlo de nuevo, se mantengan dichos cambios?

Comment: Así como te escribí en la respuesta, si el xml cambia, y **File.WriteAllText** recibe la misma ruta de parámetro, el archivo se va a sobreescribir por la versión más nueva, me explico?

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo esta linea para guardar una tabla con los valores que yo quiera

```
ds.WriteXmlSchema("Sample.xml");
```

ds es un data set que yo cree y lo actualizo cada que se da click en un boton.

Comment: ¿Qué clase u objeto es `ds`?